# if combobox text changed reset all the textbox in the form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Form` and when I select a value from a `ComboBox`, all the `TextBox`es (around150) and `Label`s below get changed with information that I get from reading a log.

The probleme is that some log don't have all the information so the field should stay empty. The issue is when a `TextBox` has previously already contained information, this infromation doesn't get reset when I change the `ComboBox`.

I tried with a `Button` that clears all the `TextBox`es, but I have 160.

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.Clear();// do it for all the textboxs
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [Steve's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42205990/5528593) answer, if you have `TextBox`es nested in other containers (such as `GroupBox`) and not all directly on your `Form`, you have to recurse into the child containers:

```
private void ClearTextBoxes(Control container)
{
    foreach(TextBox textBox in container.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        textBox.Clear();
    foreach(Control control in container.Controls)
        ClearTextBoxes(control);
}
```

and call this like that:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClearTextBoxes(this); // "this" being your Form
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
public void ResetAllTextBoxes()
{
    // Iterate over all Controls in the current form
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        // If the control is a TextBox ...
        if (control is TextBox)
            // ... clear its text
            (control as TextBox).Text = "";
}
```